# Roll a fair dice 8 times, how many outcomes are there such that every side occurred at least once?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I tried inclusion-exclusion.

There are $6^{8}$ possible outcomes, subtract off those with only 5 outcomes, add those with 4 outcomes... There are $\binom{6}{5}$ ways to choose those with 5 outcomes, $\binom{6}{4}$ to choose those with 4 outcomes...

so the answer is 
$\binom{6}{1}^8 - \binom{6}{5}\binom{5}{1}^8+\binom{6}{4}\binom{4}{1}^8-...$

Can someone tell me why this is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *inclusion/exclusion* principle:

- Include the number of outcomes with at most $6$ values, which is $\binom66\cdot6^8$
- Exclude the number of outcomes with at most $5$ values, which is $\binom65\cdot5^8$
- Include the number of outcomes with at most $4$ values, which is $\binom64\cdot4^8$
- Exclude the number of outcomes with at most $3$ values, which is $\binom63\cdot3^8$
- Include the number of outcomes with at most $2$ values, which is $\binom62\cdot2^8$
- Exclude the number of outcomes with at most $1$ values, which is $\binom61\cdot1^8$

So the total number of desired outcomes is:

$$\binom66\cdot6^8-\binom65\cdot5^8+\binom64\cdot4^8-\binom63\cdot3^8+\binom62\cdot2^8-\binom61\cdot1^8=191520$$

Comment: But this is what I did, and I got it wrong....

Comment: @Ben10: OK, I've written it slightly different than you, using $n^8$ instead of $\binom{n}{1}^8$. But the answers are equivalent, so I can't tell what's wrong with yours. Either it is not wrong, or mine is wrong too. Do you have the correct answer? If yes, then what is it? If no, then how do you know it is wrong?

Comment: The answer is given as 6!S(8,6) where S(p,q) is the stirling number of 2nd type, which gives the same answer. There might be errors in my logic/way of writing since this is an exam question and I lost points on my exam.

Comment: @Ben10: The only thing that I would consider changing in your answer (as I've already implied in the previous comment) is $\binom{n}{1}^8$ to $n^8$. But if the answer is indeed correct, then you should change that statement at the bottom which suggests that it is wrong.

Comment: @Ben10  The Stirling number of the second kind is $$S(n, k) = \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{j = 0}^{k} (-1)^{k - j} \binom{k}{j}j^n$$ Thus, $$6!S(8, 6) = 6! \cdot \frac{1}{6!}\sum_{j = 0}^{6} (-1)^{6 - j}\binom{6}{j}j^8$$ which is the number that Barak computed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach to it. So the sets that we are allowed are of the form
$$1\,2\,3\,4\,5\,6\,a\,b$$
where $a$ and $b$ are any dice value. Now let's make combinations and permute them. If $a=b$, then we have a string of 8 numbers with a digit repeated three times, which has a total number of permutations $\frac{8!}{3!}$. If $a\neq b$, then we have a string of 8 numbers with two digits repeated twice each, which has a total number of permutations $\frac{8!}{2!2!}$. There are 6 combinations such that $a=b$, and 15 combinations such that $a\neq b$. Putting this information together, the number of permutations such that each number occurs at least once is
$$6\cdot\frac{8!}{3!}+15\cdot\frac{8!}{2!\,2!}=191520$$